# Problem using StackExchange.Redis to store to Azure hosted redis cache

Tags: azure, redis, stackexchange.redis

I can never store a string value to an Azure hosted Redis Cache.  Using StackExchange.Redis version 2.0.601 and vs2015 and vs2019.  Code below has error in comments (basically even with successful ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect there no connection is established).

```
    static bool Connect()
    {           
        ConnectionMultiplexer redis; 

        try
        {
            ConfigurationOptions cfgOptions = new ConfigurationOptions
            {
                EndPoints =
                {
                    {"RedisOnMyAzureServer", myPort}
                },
                AbortOnConnectFail = false,
                Ssl = true,
                ConnectRetry = 3,
                ConnectTimeout = 10000,
                SyncTimeout = 10000,
                DefaultDatabase = 0,
                Password = "myPassword"
            };
            redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(cfgOptions);   // takes 10.5 seconds on average 
        }
        catch
        { return false; }  // never errors

        // some diagnostics follow

        if (redis.IsConnected) 
            Console.WriteLine("client connection open"); 
        else
            Console.WriteLine("client connection closed");

        if (redis.GetDatabase().IsConnected(default(RedisKey))) 
            Console.WriteLine("database connection open"); 
        else 
            Console.WriteLine("database connection closed");

        // both connection are always closed.

        try
        {
            IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();
            db.StringSet("mykey", "value");
        }
        catch
        { return false; }  // always errors 

        return true;
    }
```

Errors at last try/catch on db.StringSet method.  I get this message:

*No connection is available to service this operation: SET mykey; A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall; IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=2,Free=1021,Min=4,Max=1023), Local-CPU: n/a*

Comment: Please edit your question and include the error details.

Comment: Hi Gaurav.  I added error that happens at db.StringSet("mykey", "value");  Thanks

Comment: `AbortOnConnectFail = false` will make the SDK ignore errors in `ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect`. This is why you are only seeing it for `StringSet`. My guess would be that you have a network issue on the way to your VM. If you are using Azure Redis Cache (SaaS), then you should not use Endpoint/Server/Password, and instead try using the connection string. `ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(RedisCacheConnectionString)`

Answer (score 10):

I got same error when I set minimum TLS version to 1.2 on Azure Redis Cache, and it was caused by TLS mismatch. It was resolved by following measures.

- Add `sslprotocols=tls12` to the connection string
- Add `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384` to TLS cipher suites

Here is the details, [Remove TLS 1.0 and 1.1 from use with Azure Cache for Redis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-remove-tls-10-11)

Comment: <add key="CacheConnection" value="server:port,password=pwd,ssl=True,abortConnect=False,sslprotocols=tls12" />
Added above key in web.config and it worked